# How can I mix 2.0 stereo to surround channels over HDMI?

Tags: audio, hdmi, speakers

Is it possible to use a PC (any OS) to custom-mix sound channels into a 7.1 surround stream over HDMI?

Use case:

Surround receiver connected to 5.1 speakers (front left, front center, front right, rear left, rear right, subwoofer) and two additional speakers that are used to play stereo recordings in a different part of the room. It should be possible to use either the five surround speakers together with the subwoofer or the two additional speakers together with the subwoofer. It seems that it is not possible to map the subwoofers to both zones on my receiver (Yamaha RX-A2020, please correct me if I am wrong). It also seems that I cannot play HDMI sources in the second zone.

Specific question:

Would it be possible to set up a computer (any OS) so that it always sent a 7.1 signal to the receiver, but always mixed any surround source to 5.1 (leaving two channels quiet) and stereo either to the front left and right speakers or to the last two surround speakers (the ones that are quiet when surround sources are played) plus the subwoofer channel? This would make it possible to use the subwoofers with both the main and the auxiliary speakers (a workaround for the receivers shortcomings).